# After adding custom security to SSRS 2016 adding users/domain in site setting security giving error

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

thanks in advance,

i have installed the SSRS 2016 andthen tries adding users to it using 
**Site Settings -> Security -> Add Users/Domain**

then it worked.

Now i have configured the same SSRS using Custom Security Extension For SSRS.
and then repeated the same step but now it is giving following error

**The user or group name 'xxx.xxxx@xxx.com' is not recognized.**

when checked in fiddler it is saying

http://localhost/reports_ssrs2k16/api/v1.0/ReportServerInfo/Model.SetSystemPolicies

404 NOT FOUND.

please help.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/aa7b95ef-4f0b-4df1-a22a-ed02245cf9c1/after-adding-custom-security-to-ssrs-2016-adding-usersdomain-in-site-setting-security-giving-error?forum=sqlreportingservices

Comment: after so long debugging the application found that it was the CheckUserName() Function whose implementation was not implemented and because of that above error was occurring.